# What () -> () means in swift?

Tags: swift

```
extension Int {
    func repetitions(task: () -> ()) {
        for i in 0..<self {
            task()
        }
    }
}
```

I know that the task is parameter namer.
But I do not know what () -> ().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`() -> ()` just means `Void -> Void` - a closure that accepts no parameters and has no return value.

Comment: Thank you. Where its contents are defined?

Comment: It's a function's argument - you have to provide it yourself. Closure is an anonymous function. Example: `Int(5).repetitions({ println("foo") })`

Comment: If you need more information about what closures are and how to use them, please refer to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html).

Answer (score 4):

`() -> ()` is the type that takes no parameters and return nothing. `() -> Void` is the same meaning.

Answer (score 4):

More precisely, `() -> ()` means a closure taking a tuple with 0 values as argument and returning a tuple with zero values. Which is equivalent to saying: a closure taking no arguments and with no return value (or returning `void`)

Comment: Actually it looks like you can pass a tuple to a function (even with named parameters) combining all its parameters. Read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25583475/148357) (question of different topic, but ended up talking about that)

Comment: Yeah, that's something I wasn't expecting, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same confusion when encountering this line of code.

seeing:

```
extension Int {
    func repetition(task: () -> Void) {
        for _ in 1...self {
            task()
        }
    }
}
```

I initially thought that this function could be called by:

```
3.repetition(task: printAtree(of: 5))
```

It is only after reading the above answers that I realise () -> () refers to closures and must take closures as an argument. Hence to call the function, we use:

```
3.repetition {
    printAtree(of: 5)
}
```

Comment: You can use @autoclosure to call the method like this repetition(task: printAtree(of: 5))